# web based remote connections in c# advice

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am going to write up a webapp hosted on a windows 2003 server to allow me to connect to local and remote servers to do some basic things.

The webapp will be hosted on serverA. It will need to be able to copy files/folders from one folder to another on this server.

It will need to be able to connect to ServerB and copy files in the same way, e.g. copy \serverB\path\to\sourcefiles to \serverB\path\to\destinationfiles

ServerB hosts an installation of MSSQL 2008, I want to be able to create new database/login etc.

How do I go about this please? I've been reading a bit about Windows Authentication, Impersonation, Delegation but i don't know where to focus on.

thanks
S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest there isn't really a one size fits all complete answer to your question, however there are a number of things that you need to take into consideration early in development to ensure that your platform is built on solid foundations.

From the description you have given the most critical consideration has to be security and everything you develop has to have this at its core.  Judging by your post if the wrong person was to access your front end then they could wreak havoc.

As for the model to use, I would suggest Windows Authentication as this is built into the framework and gives you the ability to segregate into usergroups with differing levels of access.  It will also open up some of the functionality you need, i.e. network copy of files etc

As for the database management aspect, this again can easily be done via Windows Authentication as you can grant (in SQL) windows users the ability to perform certain tasks, i.e. Create Database, Create Login, drop x, etc

All this said, it of course assumes that the two servers share user credentials, i.e. domain controller etc.

Another method, would be to use the web "interface" as a pass through onto a WCF service that operates under a specific user account that has the access you need.  You would then seperately manage authentication/authorisation in a manner that you decide.

Like I said, no simple one size answer - but hopefully this will give you something to chew on.

Comment: This is a great help, thanks! I'm writing for .net 2.0 so I guess I won't be using WCF

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be WCF - a few years ago I developed something similar - the model I went for in the end was a none processing web front end that passed all requests to a remoting enabled service that did the actual work.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create new databases or logins, why can't you use the [`create database`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) and [`create login`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) commands?